Appropriate sources of understanding for non-technical stakeholders
If working software is the primary source of truth in an agile team, with techniques like self descriptive software and unit tests, how can non-technical team members and business stakeholders (like senior leadership, product managers, marketers, support and sales) understand what the software actually does at non-surface level, given they do not have the skills to access the primary source of truth?

Working software is not the primary source of truth in Agile. It's the primary measure of progress. Your stakeholders ask for stuff, and you deliver them working software that does what they asked for, and they can check by themselves. It's not really clear to me what you are asking. Perhaps you can expand on your question

@Bogdan A stakeholder asks for something. 4 years later a different stakeholder asks for something else that conflicts with the implementation of the original thing. How do you work out what needs to be done with the conflict and who needs to be involved in that, if you don't have it documented somewhere why that implementation is the way it is.

Or what about working with stakeholders who can't directly check. A stakeholder might care about whether a flag allows the system to do X when Y, but isn't able to directly trigger on demand a real world scenario where Y is the case, and doesn't have the skills to create a synthetic scenario.

@Bogdan If the software is not the primary source of truth, what is? What defines what the software should be doing?

This is where techniques like Behaviour Driven Development (BDD) can really help.
I worked on a sports betting system where the main stakeholder was a bookie with zero technical understanding. They drove the creation of BDD scenarios and although they didn't understand the details of implementation they had a very deep understanding of how the software worked. In fact I would argue they often understood it better than the developers that were working on it.

This is a complicated question with a complicated answer. What is the source of truth?

if you have no documentation and everyone that ever worked on the software left the company, then the source code is the source of truth.
if the software is supposed to implement some ISO specification, then the specification is the source of truth.
if you are using Scrum and have a Product Owner that creates, communicates, and ensures that product backlog items are understood, then they are the source of truth.
if the software you build needs to operate within the boundaries of some rules or standards, the regulatory body checking for compliance is the source of truth.
etc.

It seems to me that you expect to have every change done to the software documented and traceable and in a format that the non-technical persons  (leadership, product managers, marketers, support and sales) can read and understand. If that's the case, what will then be the source of truth? The software? Or this documentation that is supposed to 100% explain what the software does?
And when you have this documentation, do you expect to be always keps up to date to make sure it doesn't diverge from the executable product?
This will never happen.
First of all, it's simply not value add and will be extremely expensive and effort intensive to have in place. And second, even if you are willing to spend the time and money, it will for sure diverge, because people make mistakes, forget, and misunderstand things. The software could also have bugs. Even if things were clear and understood, you can mess it up when you write the code. So in these case, the truth becomes blurry. And when it does, what do you do?
You do the same thing that you would have done if you didn't have these things in place: collaborate with various people to figure out what's going on, and if it's correct, you gained some understanding, and if it's not, then you change it.
You have some requirements that you use to build something. People check it is working as expected. Then after a while maybe they ask to change it to respond to some new market conditions. You build it and they check again that it works as expected. And things can go on like this until 4 years later a different stakeholder asks for something else that conflicts with the implementation of the original thing.
I would ask at this point: how do you know it's a conflict?
Do you or the users familiar with the app know that's not how things work? Do you have a requirement document laying around that explains how it's implemented and why? Do you perhaps have a Jira ticket where this was requested initially? Has a developer looked in the code already and the new requirement doesn't make much sense? Has some unit or integration test failed when the new behavior was put in place?
And this was built 4 years ago. Is that even relevant now?
Like I said, collaborate with various people to figure out what's going on, and if it's correct, you gained some understanding, and if it's not, then you change it. Having a place where everything is documented or you can track every change helps to limit the back and forth, but the conflicting change still needs to be resolved, and might have to be implemented anyways if the old context doesn't make sense anymore.
So until AI replaces us all and you have requirements written by non-technical people that the AI could flawlessly interpret and implement into working software, you have multiple potential sources of truth to rely on, even if occasionally conflicting.

In the worst case, it gets to production and breaks things. Because no one involved in the new change was involved in the original change and the testing isn't sufficient. At which point it potentially extremely expensive to fix if you aren't lucky enough to have some form of rapid/continuous deployment.

If you do an effort to understand things before deploying to production, you won’t break things. And even if with best efforts you do end up introducing a breaking change, then in Agile you have inspect and adapt events that you can use, to take the lesson learned, and find ways to update your processes so that you don’t break things in the future. And if you are truly Agile (not by name only) then you should invest in a continuous delivery pipeline anyways, to allow you to deploy or rollback changes quickly.

A continuous delivery approach may be ideal, but is not always simple/inexpensive. Its a lot more challenging to pull off when you are building on-premise software for customers with multi-month manual approval processes (customer, not internal) for installing versions to their systems. And trying to find a lesson learned was what lead to me asking this question, after repeated failures, none of which have common root process failings other than 'historically no one wrote tests to cover this case, and no one in the process involved knew it was an issue'.

Working software is not the primary source of truth.
In the 12 Principles behind the Agile Manifesto, "working software is the primary measure of progress". Stakeholders see that the team is making progress by seeing and using working software. By delivering working software frequently (another principle), the team can be given confidence that they are satisfying the stakeholders' needs (yet another principle). And if the software isn't meeting the needs of the stakeholders, they welcome changing requirements (also a principle).
For some people, the current state of the software may be a primary source of truth. To the development team, for example, the current state of code, configuration, and tests reflects the reality of what the system is far more than any other type of requirements, architecture, or design documentation that says what the system should do. However, the code, configuration, and tests may not reflect what the stakeholders want or need from the system.
The users of the system should understand what the system actually does, since they are the ones using it. They can observe how the system responds to inputs and know if they desire or expect those responses. If the responses meet expectations and desires, then the system is meeting their needs. However, if the system doesn't respond as expected or desired or the behaviors that are wanted aren't part of the system, then the system needs to change and evolve.
The person who is ultimately accountable for defining what the system is supposed to do and resolving conflicts varies depending on the organization and the processes used to build the system. Scrum, as an example, has the Product Owner accountabilities. DSDM has roles and responsibilities like the Business Sponsor, Business Visionary, Business Advisor, and Business Ambassador. Extreme Programming has the concept of the "on-site customer". People in roles such as these are empowered to represent the various stakeholder groups and remove any conflicts in requests, making the decision on what the system should do.
Systems aren't static over time. Functionality implemented one way weeks, months, or years ago may become invalid or incorrect as the world changes. The empowered individuals on the team are responsible for understanding and communicating these changes to the development team. Techniques such as architectural decision records, tools that enable traceability between work items (as examples, issues recorded in Jira or GitHub or some other work management tool) and changes to code and configuration, and comments (inline or in commit messages in the version control system) let the team understand why certain implementation decisions were made, while test cases can capture the assumptions and expectations and automating those test cases (especially when those automated test cases are captured in the domain language, using practices from specification by example, behavior-driven development, and acceptance test-driven development) can raise cases where expectations are no longer satisfied.

You mention the product owner in scrum is supposed to be the one that is empowered to handle conflict. But how are they supposed to track that a conflict even exists in a complex system where the requests may be separated by years, and the first user is happy with the way the system is, and doesn't want the seconds change? Having the records in code and comments is all very well, but the product owner doesn't know they exist, and may not even know what to ask for.

Especially considering the users may not even be aware of each others needs and desires.

Additionally, whilst the users may have desires and needs, doesn't mean that the system necessarily fulfills that need. A user may have a need for payroll processing, but that doesn't mean the warehouse inventory software should fill that need. Somewhere the decision needs to be made about which needs and which users are within the scope of the business product. Where are those decisions and the understand of that scope expected to live, as opposed to just accepting every request that comes in, regardless of if it makes sense for the product?

@user1937198, the latest point at which the product owner becomes aware of a conflict is when a developer comes to them and says that he cannot keep some existing tests passing when implementing the new feature.

@user1937198 When a request comes in, in Scrum, the accountability to understand it, make sure it aligns with the product vision and objectives, and convey the request to the developers is the Product Owner. Roles with similar responsibilities and accountabilities exist in other processes. The developers and testers, by looking at the work (through what Scrum calls Product Backlog refinement), they may raise concerns or conflicts for the Product Owner to resolve. The latest is at development, when, like Bart van Ingen Schenau says, automated tests fail.
